# SQL How to select "id_owner" that contains all cars from a list

Tags: sql, select, contains

I'm trying to retrieve a list of "id_owner" from a fictional table of cars and their owners (e.g.  "id", "owner_id", "carname"). This list of owners should contain all cars from another list.

it should be like: 
`SELECT id_owner FROM ownedcars WHERE carname = "Ferrari"  or carname = "Mustang" or carname = "Porsche"`

I think its needed to do it in a subquery because all the ways I tried, the list returns all id_owners that contain any of car of this list, instead of contain all three cars of the list

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column1 LIKE '%word1%'
  AND column1 LIKE '%word2%'
  AND column1 LIKE '%word3%'`
like this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `group by` and `having`.

```
SELECT id_owner 
FROM ownedcars 
WHERE carname in ('Ferrari','Mustang','Porsche')
GROUP BY id_owner
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT carname) = 3
```

Comment: It worked pretty well. I thought it would be alot harder to understand

Answer (score 0):

> I think its needed to do it in a subquery because all the ways I
>   tried, the list returns all id_owners that contain any of car of this
>   list, instead of contain all three cars of the list

Based on the message above, you could use EXISTS operator to achieve your goal.

```
SELECT id_owner FROM ownedcars T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ownedcars WHERE carname='Ferrari' AND id_owner=T.id_owner)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ownedcars WHERE carname='Mustang' AND id_owner=T.id_owner)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ownedcars WHERE carname='Porsche' AND id_owner=T.id_owner)
```

Best Regards,

Will